# HTML - tag name as attribute - is valid and how to use?

Tags: html, markup, custom-attributes

Is such `html` markup valid?

```
<icon="pen"/>
```

And if so, how to manage it like via `jQuery`?

Comment: What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: Simplify markup as Einstein said : "as simple as possible, but not simpler"

Comment: 'Simplify markup'? I think HTML(5) is already quite simple. There are standards, and it's better to follow them.

Comment: Don't confuse "short" and "simple"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not valid. Don't do that.

There is a *proposal* for a [custom elements](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/) spec, which could make `icon` allowable.

But following the element name with an `=` character is simply wrong.